# Is there a way to remove influence of selected bones on multiple selected vertices?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

When correcting the weight painting of my mesh, parts of my character's torso seem to stick to a few of my character's arm bones (of which my character has many) so I have to check the weight painting of each arm bone to see if it is affecting the torso.
Is there a way to select the mesh vertices of the torso, then select the arm bones in pose mode then applying some sort of "remove all influence from these bones from selected vertices" functionality.

The closest thing I've found is to select each vertex of the torso in weight paint mode and deleting all the Arm bone vertex weights like so:
[image: delete vertex weights]
But this can only be done for one vertex at a time (selecting multiple vertices this way only shows the vertex weights of the vertex that was last selected) so it is incredibly slow.

Is there a faster way to do this?